# Flutter Android not displaying Ukraine letters correctly

Tags: android, flutter, dart, localization

My app is localized to Ukraine but somehow it is not displaying some letters. This **only happens on Android**, on iOS everything is working fine!

Here is an example:

[image]

The button title is:

> Далі

How can I fix this? Is this a known Flutter issue? Couldn't find anything on this.

Here is the `pubspec`:

```
  fonts:
    - family: Avenir-Next
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/avenir_next/AvenirNext-Bold.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/avenir_next/AvenirNext-Demi.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/avenir_next/AvenirNext-Regular.ttf
```

Comment: Are you using a font that has the right range of glyphs?  You might need to load a custom font.  See the package:google_fonts for one source of fonts.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz but how come this is working on iOS? Its the same font.

Comment: The core font on android is Roboto.  It's something else on iOS.

Comment: weird, I am using `avenir-next`

Comment: Can you identify the source of your font. Found [this post regarding avenir-next](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/115256/22600) but realize that the font engines on each platform is different, so testing with a different font may be required.

Comment: @MorrisonChang what exactly do you mean by "source of my font" ?

Comment: How are you including it in your app (with what code), is it a Google font, downloaded from a 'free typeface' site, part of a library or custom component. Do realize that Flutter iOS defaults to [Impeller engine](https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/impeller) while Android is the old renderer so you may be seeing differences. You also haven't stated if changing the font fixes the issue.

Comment: can you paste here your pubspec declaration for font?

Comment: Could you please try this package https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts, it seems to me that it will solve your problem.

Comment: @MorrisonChang updated the question with the `pubspec`. Also, i am not using `google_fonts` since Avenir-Next is not a google font.

Comment: Are you fetching these strings using an API? If yes, are you sure these are decoded or parsed correctly? But it should have been issue on both platforms.

Comment: @RoHaN these strings are hard coded in. And working on iOS

Comment: Are you sure the font is correctly being used? If you remove the fontFamily from the TextStyle or theme, is there any visual changes on the text?

Comment: @DhafinRayhan what do you mean by "correctly used"? How can I use it incorrectly? :D It is working perfectly for other languages

Comment: It is possible that you think you're using that Avenir-Next font, but Flutter doesn't read that due to some mistake. So I ask you to check whether the the letters still not being displayed if you change the font. It is not possible for us to know if you're using the font correctly or not because you're not showing any part of the code where you actually use that font in your TextStyle or theme